# python time series synthetic data using ydata-synthetic package - Time series GAN

Tags: python, time-series, generative-adversarial-network

hello like a title i try to using synthetic package for Time series GAN
at the first time i was thinking putting integer then output also numerical but it wasn't, output data are decimal number  i using ydata-synthetic (https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic)

here is my code for make data please help me

#Importing the required libs for the exercise

```
from os import path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from ydata_synthetic.synthesizers import ModelParameters
from ydata_synthetic.preprocessing.timeseries import processed_stock
from ydata_synthetic.synthesizers.timeseries import TimeGAN
import torch


arr_data = np.random.randint(0,600000,(100,1))

#Specific to TimeGANs

#stock_data
seq_len=20
n_seq = 1  #number of columns


hidden_dim=24
gamma=1

noise_dim = 32
dim = 128
batch_size = len(arr_data) - seq_len

log_step = 100
learning_rate = 5e-4

gan_args = ModelParameters(batch_size=batch_size,
                           lr=learning_rate,
                           noise_dim=noise_dim,
                           layers_dim=dim)


lst_temp = []
for i in range(0,len(arr_data) - seq_len):
    _x = arr_data[i:i+20]
    lst_temp.append(_x)

tens_rand_data = torch.tensor(lst_temp)
lst_rand_data = tens_rand_data.numpy()

synth = TimeGAN(model_parameters=gan_args, hidden_dim=24, seq_len=seq_len, n_seq=n_seq, gamma=1)

synth.train(lst_rand_data, train_steps=10)
synth_data = synth.sample(len(lst_rand_data))
print(synth_data.shape)

cols = ['Car price']

for j, col in enumerate(cols):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Real': lst_rand_data[-1][:, j],'Synthetic': synth_data[-1][:, j]})
    
df.plot(title = "Car price",secondary_y='Synthetic data', style=['-', '--'])

print(df)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDGyS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your input should be processed using a MinMaxScaler before fitting into TimeGAN, and you will always receive decimal output between 0 and 1 due to sigmoid activation on the last layer of its Generator.

You can change your code in 2 ways:

1. Change your input from integer to decimal range [0,1].

   ```
   arr_data = np.random.randint(0,600000,(100,1))
   ```

   into

   ```
   arr_data = np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,1))
   ```

   This way your dummy input doesn't need to be scaler since it's already in [0,1].
2. Use MinMaxScaler to scale your data

   ```
   from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

   arr_data = np.random.randint(0,600000,(100,1))

   scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
   scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(arr_data)

   ...
   ```

   Please note that you will always receive decimal output from [0,1] when using TimeGAN. Now if you want to inverse synthetic data into integer, consider using [inverse transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform).